# Dataproc Java client throws NoSuchMethodError setUseJwtAccessWithScope

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am following this [article](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job) ,for submit a job to an existing Dataproc cluster via a Dataproc API

For the following line of code :

```
 // Configure the settings for the job controller client.
    JobControllerSettings jobControllerSettings =
        JobControllerSettings.newBuilder().setEndpoint(myEndpoint).build();
```

I am getting the following errors :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider$Builder com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider$Builder.setUseJwtAccessWithScope(boolean)'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider$Builder com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider$Builder.setUseJwtAccessWithScope(boolean)'
```

In my pom I used the following dependencies :

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>24.1.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

And added the dataproc

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataproc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Any help what I am missing here?

Comment: From where are your run that code? If out of Google Cloud (on your local workstation or on another cloud/on-prem environment, which type of authentication do you use?

Comment: yes it's on my local machine, I am authenticated using end user credentials

Comment: Sadly, you have to use a service account key file. The library create a JWT and try to add scope. It's  not possible to create ID Token with user credential and google cloud auth....

Comment: Are you submitting with gcloud? Could you share your command?

Comment: Could you try using the [service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) ? It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider$Builder com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider$Builder.setUseJwtAccessWithScope(boolean)` was introduced in `com.google.api:gax` in version [2.3.0](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java/releases/tag/v2.3.0).

Can you

1. run `mvn dependency:tree` and confirm that your version of `com.google.api:gax` is above version 2.3.0?
2. upgrade all Google libraries to the latest version?

Here is a [similar issue](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-graalvm-support/211) found on the internet.